# How to show collections in blender 2.8

Tags: collections, visibility

I was creating a project in blender 2.8. I unintentionally pressed the 1 button, and now only one of the objects (each object is inside a collection) appears on the screen. All other objects are hidden.

How can I see the collections again? I don't want to loose all the work of the previous hours.

Besides, something as basic as that should have documentation. One hour of search in google, stackoverflow, and the blender 2.8 documentation for terms like "unhide collections" or "show all collections" or "unhide objects" do not return any working solution. This was a basic feature of blender 2.7. What happened?

Obs: Alt+H does nothing.

Answer (score 11):

TL;DR: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> in the Outliner ([thanks @aliasguru](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150996/how-to-show-collections-in-blender-2-8/151003?noredirect=1#comment258002_151003)).

---

There are a few ways to hide/show collections in 2.8:

- In the Outliner area (by default there's one in the top right), clicking the eye icon toggles visibility of the corresponding collection.
- Pressing number-row numbers (<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> etc.) will switch to the nth collection (according to the order in the outliner), hiding the others.
- Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + number will toggle visibility for the nth collection.
- There is a collections section in the 3D view > <kbd>N</kbd> panel > View tab. This one seems to be the most convenient for toggling visibility on lots of collections quickly, using the click+drag toggle behavior.

[image]

- Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> in the 3D view brings up a "hide collection" dialog which behaves like like pressing numbers (switches to the clicked collection hiding the others).
- As noted previously, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> in the Outliner unhides all collections.

Also important to note, that the old *hide in viewport*/*hide in render* properties still exist on collections and are completely separate from the visibility set by the controls describe above. Controls for those can be found in the right click menu in the outliner, under *Visibility*:

[image]

I'm not really sure why it works this way currently, I wouldn't be surprised if it changes in subsequent releases.

Comment: There ist a Show all collections, but only in the outliner. Press Alt+h in the outliner.

Comment: @gandalf3, nice but how do you switch on collection 11, 12 and beyond?