# Is anybody else accidentally hiding collections in blender 2.8?

Tags: shortcut, collections

often i forget i'm not in edit mode and i will press 1, 2, or 3. If you're in object mode it will hide all the collections i'm working with. Alt+H doesn't seem to unhide them and i have to manually make them visible again in the outliner. Is there another efficient way to work to avoid this problem?

Comment: You could try having a look at the shortcuts? Possibly disabling them, or changing them to something else. Although I can't seem to replicate what yo're doing...

Comment: as much as I preferred 2.7's shortcuts, I'm trying to adapt to 2.8's default shortcuts as much as possible. So when you're in object mode and you have multiple custom-named collections, hitting 1,2, or 3 doesn't hide all those collections? Is it just me?

Comment: With 2.8 shortcuts 1, 2, 3 don't do anything I can notice.

Comment: nevermind, i found my answer here:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150996/how-to-show-collections-in-blender-2-8
thanks anyways