# Hotkeys 1,2,3 in Object Mode

Tags: interface

What do these hotkeys do in object mode? I accidentally did this in object mode and now the whole file is screwed up. Objects are invisible even though the eye icon is white in the outliner. same case for being able to select an object. I there any way to revert to the default state?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Search for the keymap**

[image]

Go to *`Edit > Preferences > Keymaps`* and search for any keymap using <kbd>1</kbd>

Will notice that in object mode it is set to hide  collection.

See [How to show collections in blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150996/how-to-show-collections-in-blender-2-8)

Comment: Followed the link and read it up. Alt + H on the outliner managed to resolve this! Thanks alot!