# Pressed 1 or ` now mesh is gone

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view, blend-files

I think I hid a mesh (named "rims" in attachment) and then created a cylinder. After accidentally hitting <kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>`</kbd> (I'm not sure) the cylinder is gone even though appears as showing in the scene.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> doesn't work; cannot even bring the hidden mesh back.

[image]

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> or toggling the eye icon does not make mesh 'rims' or 'cylinder' visible.

How can I view meshes again?

[image]

Comment: pressing the top row number keys allows to display only the collection 1 or 2 or 3, etc... it may be your problem here? take a look at the Outliner visibility settings

Comment: The collection itself is hidden too. Enable "Chasis" in the outliner

Comment: @moonboots Had to unhide the collection as a whole; unhiding individual members does not work.

Comment: You have some details on collection visibility here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150996/how-to-show-collections-in-blender-2-8

Comment: I don't know how to display collection 11 and beyond though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you press the <kbd>1</kbd> key in object mode, it hides all the collections except the first one. Likewise, if you press <kbd>2</kbd> it will hide all the collections except for the second one, and so on.

To unhide a collection click the eye icon to the right of the name of the collection. [image: Place where to click to unhide collection.]